Ipsec between Solaris 10 and Linux: fail, what to check?
I want to make (just for learning, testing ipsec) a tunnel between a Linux machine and Solaris 10 machine (i know Solaris 11 is more safe and maybe easy for ipsec, but I have Solaris 10 atm).
The Solaris 10 and Linux are both virtual machines.
On Solaris 10 I configured a nic with ip 10.8.2.2/24 and on Linux I use 10.8.2.3, Solaris is left side, Linux Right side The two nics are connected via virtual-switch, and works (all in clear of course)
On Solaris 10 this is the ipsec configuration
vim /etc/inet/ike/config
p1_xform
  { auth_method preshared oakley_group 5 auth_alg sha encr_alg 3des }
p2_pfs 2
{ label "test1-test2" local_addr 10.6.0.1 remote_addr 10.6.0.2 p1_xform { auth_method preshared oakley_group 5 auth_alg  
sha256 encr_alg aes } p2_pfs 5 }
{ label "test2-test3" local_addr 10.8.2.2 remote_addr 10.8.2.3 p1_xform { auth_method preshared oakley_group 5 auth_alg  
md5 encr_alg 3des } p2_pfs 5 }

vim /etc/inet/secret/ike.preshared
{ localidtype IP
    localid 10.8.2.2
    remoteidtype IP
    remoteid 10.8.2.3
    key ********************HEXKEY
    # The preshared key can also be represented in hex
# as in 0xf47cb0f432e14480951095f82b
# key "This is an ASCII Cqret phrAz, use str0ng p@ssword tekniques"
}

vim /etc/inet/ipsecinit.conf
{laddr 10.8.2.2 raddr 10.8.2.3} ipsec {encr_algs 3des encr_auth_algs md5 sa shared}

On Linux side (Slackware 15, with libreswan 5.1)
vim /etc/ipsec.d/mytunnel.conf
conn mytunnel

       auto=start
       keyexchange=ikev1
       phase2=esp
       pfs=no
       type=tunnel
       authby=secret
       left=10.8.2.3
       right=10.8.2.2
       esp=3des-md5

vim /etc/ipsec.d/mytunnel.secrets
10.8.2.3 10.8.2.2 : PSK "SAMEHEXASSOLARIS"

I restart ipsec on both sides
for Solaris
for i in ike ipsec/policy;do svcadm refresh $i; done

for Linux
/etc/rc.d/rc.ipsec restart

I run tunnel on Linux
  ipsec auto --add mytunnel
    WARNING: ipsec auto has been deprecated
    "mytunnel": terminating SAs using this connection
    "mytunnel" #12: deleting ISAKMP SA (MAIN_I1) aged 63.374831s and NOT sending notification
    "mytunnel" #13: initiating IKEv1 Main Mode connection
    "mytunnel" #13: sent Main Mode request
    "mytunnel": added IKEv1 connection

and finally..all in clear. :|
With tcpdump is report all traffic in clear + this error message
 10.8.2.3.isakmp > 10.8.2.2.isakmp: [bad udp cksum 0x1db6 -> 0xc302!] isakmp 1.0 msgid 00000000 cookie 240a064c7603aab2->0000000000000000: phase 1 I ident:

on Solaris syslog said..
Dec 28 12:47:58 solaris10 ip: [ID 726330 kern.error] ipsec_check_global_policy: Dropping inbound unprotected datagram because it does not match the policy; Source 010.008.002.003, Destinatio
n 010.008.002.002.
Dec 28 12:49:20 solaris10 last message repeated 70 times
Dec 28 12:56:12 solaris10 ip: [ID 726330 kern.error] ipsec_check_global_policy: Dropping inbound unprotected datagram because it does not match the policy; Source 010.008.002.003, Destinatio
n 010.008.002.002.
Dec 28 12:56:20 solaris10 last message repeated 8 times
Dec 28 13:01:22 solaris10 ip: [ID 726330 kern.error] ipsec_check_global_policy: Dropping inbound unprotected datagram because it does not match the policy; Source 010.008.002.003, Destinatio
n 010.008.002.002.

What i miss?
I know ikev1 is not strong, but is only for testing, for 3des is only for testing too.

Solution found. Instead of using tunnel I must use transport
On Solaris:
/etc/inet/ike/config
p1_xform
  { auth_method preshared oakley_group 5 auth_alg sha encr_alg aes }
p2_pfs 2
{ label "test1-test2" local_addr 10.6.0.1 remote_addr 10.6.0.2 p1_xform { auth_method preshared oakley_group 5 auth_alg  sha256 encr_alg aes } p2_pfs 5 }
{ label "test2-test3" local_addr 10.8.2.2 remote_addr 10.8.2.3 p1_xform { auth_method preshared oakley_group 5 auth_alg   sha256 encr_alg aes } p2_pfs 5 }

/etc/inet/ipsecinit.conf
{laddr 10.7.2.1 dir both} bypass {}
{laddr 10.6.0.1 raddr 10.6.0.2} ipsec {encr_algs aes encr_auth_algs sha256 sa shared}
{laddr 10.8.2.2 raddr 10.8.2.3} ipsec {encr_algs aes encr_auth_algs sha256 sa shared}

/etc/inet/secret/ike.preshared
# ike.preshared on hostA

{ localidtype IP
    localid 10.8.2.2
    remoteidtype IP
    remoteid 10.8.2.3
    key KEYINHEXFORMAT
    # The preshared key can also be represented in hex
# as in 0xf47cb0f432e14480951095f82b
#key "This is an ASCII Cqret phrAz, use str0ng p@ssword tekniques"
}

{ localidtype IP
    localid 10.6.0.1
    remoteidtype IP
    remoteid 10.6.0.2
    key KEYINHEXFORMAT
    # The preshared key can also be represented in hex
# as in 0xf47cb0f432e14480951095f82b
#key "This is an ASCII Cqret phrAz, use str0ng p@ssword tekniques"
}

on Linux (libreswan)
vim /etc/ipsec.d/mytunnel.conf
conn mytunnel

authby=secret
#keyexchange=ikev1
left=10.8.2.3
right=10.8.2.2
fragmentation=no
pfs=no
auto=start
#type=tunnel #WRONG!
type=transport
keyexchange=ikev1
#keyingtries=3 

/etc/ipsec.secrets
 10.8.2.3 10.8.2.2 : PSK "passwordincleartxt" 

On Solaris I restart the services
for i in ike ipsec/policy;do svcadm disable -t $i; done
for i in ike ipsec/policy;do svcadm enable  $i; done 

On Linux too
/etc/init.d/ipsec restart

I start the tunnel and works fine
ipsec auto --add mytunnel
WARNING: ipsec auto has been deprecated
"mytunnel": terminating SAs using this connection
"mytunnel" #2: deleting IPsec SA (QUICK_I2) aged 32.208921s and sending notification using ISAKMP SA #1
"mytunnel" #2: ESP traffic information: in=0B out=0B
"mytunnel" #1: deleting ISAKMP SA (MAIN_I4) aged 32.257586s and sending notification
"mytunnel" #3: initiating IKEv1 Main Mode connection
"mytunnel" #3: sent Main Mode request
"mytunnel": added IKEv1 connection
root@slackware1:~# ipsec auto --up mytunnel
WARNING: ipsec auto has been deprecated
"mytunnel" #5: initiating Quick Mode IKEv1+PSK+ENCRYPT+TUNNEL+UP+ESN_NO+ESN_YES {using isakmp#3 msgid:9468f301 proposal=AES_CBC-HMAC_SHA1_96, AES_CBC-HMAC_SHA2_512_256, AES_CBC-HMAC_SHA2_256_128, AES_GCM_16_128-NONE, AES_GCM_16_256-NONE, 3DES_CBC-HMAC_SHA1_96, 3DES_CBC-HMAC_SHA2_512_256, 3DES_CBC-HMAC_SHA2_256_128 pfsgroup=no-pfs}
"mytunnel" #5: sent Quick Mode request
"mytunnel" #5: IPsec SA established tunnel mode {ESP=>0x0b143a67 <0x83a2d573 xfrm=AES_CBC_128-HMAC_SHA1_96 DPD=passive}

Ping works.
Tcpdump report ESP is used, good!
  10.8.2.3 > 10.8.2.2: ESP(spi=0xf37e9bdc,seq=0x8), length 120
    0x0000:  4500 008c 3d59 4000 4032 e4d2 0a08 0203  E...=Y@.@2......
    0x0010:  0a08 0202 f37e 9bdc 0000 0008 ebf8 1114  .....~..........
    0x0020:  2d80 19ef eb7f bff6 9c7d e1d1 58ae a78d  -........}..X...
    0x0030:  3a69 f2e3 275a 6c21 f0cf d9a6 b453 1922  :i..'Zl!.....S."
    0x0040:  92d4 2f19 7edc 90cc d000 3f28 fe36 1d23  ../.~.....?(.6.#
    0x0050:  5b09 30eb a091 6233 a8e7 5b79 aca8 3db2  [.0...b3..[y..=.
    0x0060:  eb35 23f6 afec ca33 e159 7590 e062 2b58  .5#....3.Yu..b+X
    0x0070:  7c47 9908 085b b093 0dc4 ecdd 515e 6c46  |G...[......Q^lF
    0x0080:  0a8b f35b 24a6 f93e 889e cdd8            ...[$..>....
20:29:24.836576 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 53793, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ESP (50), length 140)
    10.8.2.2 > 10.8.2.3: ESP(spi=0x408dd35d,seq=0x8), length 120
    0x0000:  4500 008c d221 4000 ff32 9109 0a08 0202  E....!@..2......
    0x0010:  0a08 0203 408d d35d 0000 0008 a731 143d  ....@..].....1.=
    0x0020:  22da 550e a6a1 6dee 8da2 d0c2 c2dc 64e4  ".U...m.......d.
    0x0030:  0bf6 a74b a032 0981 967d 6e52 e826 dc86  ...K.2...}nR.&..
    0x0040:  5fe4 02be 3a13 5f9d 2c6b 89d2 1219 a1ce  _...:._.,k......
    0x0050:  9f51 03b4 9165 b2a2 506c e030 df78 f5ee  .Q...e..Pl.0.x..
    0x0060:  cfa0 501d 2d4e 9177 aecd cdfa cf9b 5ad7  ..P.-N.w......Z.
    0x0070:  e3f3 0001 cebb 1498 e8b4 9d51 0f9c 080d  ...........Q....
    0x0080:  4edd d975 4519 e568 cec4 8a0b            N..uE..h....

